# Como parar uma progressbar no Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

Sempre desenvolvi em JS to meio perdido aqui no Python, se puderem me ajudar...

Queria deixar o botão fechar sem evento até a barra de progresso acabar, e que a barra de progresso ao terminar fique "indeterminate"

```
    #Loading page

    root = Tk()
    # Titulo da janela 2

    root.title("Carregando aplicação...")
    janela["bg"] = "white"

    # Tamanho da janela default 2

    root.geometry("230x100+500+500")
    progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root,orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
    progressbar.place(x=15,y=25)

    progressbar.start(50)

    def fechar():
        root.destroy()


    bt_root_close = Button(root,width=20,text="Fechar", command=fechar)
    bt_root_close.pack(side="bottom")
```

Obrigado!

Comment: basta usares `progressbar.stop()`

Comment: Então mas quando eu uso, uso abaixo do Start e essa tela começa pausada, a barra não vai até o final, sabe?

Comment: Tenta desabilitar o botão dentro de uma condicional da barra então quan da barra terminar o botão fechar estará habilitado